# How to use FirebaseAnimatedList and SplashScreen?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am fetching data from firebase and showing it in a list. But once the page is opened it's empty for few seconds because it takes time to fetch the data and display. So I want to display a splash/loading screen and in the background load the other page making it ready with fetched data. So that once that page is shown it won't be empty, but displaying content fetched. Please help me how to do it ?

This is the way I display the list fetching from firebase. I use

```
FirebaseAnimatedList.
 body: FirebaseAnimatedList(
  query: itemRef,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
      Animation<double> animation, int index) {
    return Text('It work ');
}),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to use `defaultChild` property inside [**FirebaseAnimatedList**](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/ui_firebase_animated_list/FirebaseAnimatedList-class.html) widget.

**Example with your code**:

```
 body: FirebaseAnimatedList(
  defaultChild: SplashScreen(),
  query: itemRef,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
      Animation<double> animation, int index) {
    return Text('It work ');
}),
```

`defaultChild` is the widget that is displayed while the request is loading.

You can learn more about **FirebaseAnimatedList** **[here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/ui_firebase_animated_list/FirebaseAnimatedList-class.html)**

Comment: I am using a FirebaseAnimatedList to fetch the list of items.

`body: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: itemRef,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          return (index % 4 == 0)
              ? Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(`

Comment: Please tell me how to do it if I use FirebaseAnimatedList to display the list fetching from firebase. I've updated the question with my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FutureBuilder, and once your data is loaded remove the SplashScreen:

```
    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
        future: _firebaseData,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            List<String> firebaseData = snapshot.data; 
            return ListView( [...]
           }
           else
                return SplashScreen();
);
```

Comment: Please tell me how to do it if I use FirebaseAnimatedList to display the list fetching from firebase. I've updated the question with my sample code.